# Alternatives for Tree structure

Tags: hierarchy, tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to view a deep hierarchy?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/whats-the-best-way-to-view-a-deep-hierarchy)

In a desktop application what are the innovative, alternate methods to a tree structure?

Provide me some example links to go through.

Comment: There are many similar if not duplicate questions like yours. Also, please help us answer you and provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. A good start would be over there in the "Related" section ------------------->

Comment: What is going to be the purpose of the tree structure?

Answer (score 13):

### For arbitrary numbers of levels:

- Cascading windows

[image: Cascading Windows]

- There are numerous possible presentations of tree hierarchies.  The variants shown below are all from http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/, which is web based, but nothing stops the algorithms being used to render hierarchies in a desktop application:

[image: Protovis Hierarchies]

- Google's [Image Swirl](http://image-swirl.googlelabs.com/html?q=ferris%20wheel&pq=wheel&ps=5682873ba4907018&cluster=1181#1195) is a web based tree browsing of images - similar presentation could be used for a desktop application - and in any case a web browser is a desktop application.  Modern application development tools can make including a browser window in an application a good choice.
- The Open Source [Walrus Program](https://www.caida.org/tools/visualization/walrus/) provides interactive 3D visualizations of very large trees.
- Any method for showing networks can equally show a tree, because a tree is just a network with the least links necessary to stay connected in one piece.
- [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/) can be used to generate displays of trees of all kinds.  This circular example below is for visualizing the [hailstone sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).  Another program, [Circos,](http://circos.ca/intro/genomic_data/) specializes in diagrams in a circular format, and as well as networks can also show tree structured data.

[image]

- Menus are a form of tree.  So are menus in disguise like Microsoft's Ribbon.
- Miller Columns

[image: Miller Columns]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://www.google.com/url?source=imgres&ct=img&q=http://www.informit.com/content/images/chap03_9780789742292/elementLinks/03fig06.jpg&sa=X&ei=Np_QTOyzFIKBlAemrNHvBQ&ved=0CAQQ8wc4Qg&usg=AFQjCNHUJc55AvHYbMaw_m9TrZfFoV_gDQ))</sub>

### For one or two levels:

- Accordions
- Tabbed control
- One nested inside the other to get to two levels.

### For a small fixed number of levels

- A table with a column for each level, each row representing one leaf node and giving the full breadcrumbs-path to the node represented.
- Table using indents

[image: Indented Table]

- Most of the methods in [Tag-wiki Master Details](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/master-details/info)
- Other examples are in topics discussed under [hierarchy](/questions/tagged/hierarchy) such as [What's the best way to view a deep hierarchy?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/whats-the-best-way-to-view-a-deep-hierarchy)

Comment: That screenshot of the Finder is much better than the one I put in the other question...

Comment: And now they're the same :) - re-used from [What's the best way to view a deep hierarchy?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/whats-the-best-way-to-view-a-deep-hierarchy)

Answer (score 8):

**Multi level pie menu**

[image: picture of Multi level pie menu]

**Tree map**

[image: picture of Treemap]

**Zoomable interface**

[image: picture of Zoomable Interface]