# Chrome Options UI Pattern Name

Tags: design-patterns, layout

I've been looking for a way to organize hierarchical data. I came across the UI in Chrome Options. I really like it and think will work well for what I need. Is there a name to this pattern?

As you can see, you can jump in between levels. When you click on an option that has sub-options a new tab slides open.

Follow up question, does anyone know of a jquery plug-in with similar functionality?

[image: Chrome Options]

Comment: Inspecting the element within Chrome, the CSS describes itself as a *subpage sheet*, but googling that doesn't come up with much other than google groups/forums.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the first app to do this was Twitter for iPad and it was hailed as fairly innovative as a result. As such I haven't come across a name for the pattern yet. It might be worth contacting someone on the Twitter iPad design team to find out if they have an internal name for it (asking on Quora may help as there's a greater concentration of designers and other valley residents there).

Designer [Emily Chang refers to them as "sliding panels"](http://emilychang.com/2010/09/twitter-for-ipad/).

Raw engineering built an open-source library of code called "[Stack Scroll View](http://www.raweng.com/blog/stack-scroll-view/)".

[image: Twitter for iPad]

Your question about jQuery is probably best asked on StackOverflow or Doctype rather than here.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think the sliding panels or stacked scroll view really caters for the hierarchical nature of the pages and that if you interact with a middle page then all subpages are closed automatically. They are more mechanisms to handle multiple pages at once with the ability to slide/scroll/drag them to one side?

Comment: @Roger Attrill >> They are more mechanisms to handle multiple pages at once with the ability to slide/scroll/drag << Examples? I read this Q/A http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/whats-the-best-way-to-view-a-deep-hierarchy but none of them seem well suited for the web and my needs.