# How can I show deep level hierarchical data with different types of data?

Tags: hierarchy, tree

Is there a best practice or pattern that resolves this potential issue? I have a tree that could be pretty large but also ti could contain few children/leafs.

One important aspect is that some children contains data that takes time to load. Therefore the tree is lazyloading that is it is loading data on demand.

[image]

Comment: There're multiple versions of this same question in the `Related` section of the sidebar. For example, [What's the best way to view a deep hierarchy?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/whats-the-best-way-to-view-a-deep-hierarchy)

Comment: I have seen the question linked. They just cover different ways of showing hierarchical data. In my case i have to consider "delay" of loading leaf/child data and how to make a progress indicator of some kind flow with the layout and ux. I hope i make any sense here.

Comment: You just add a visual indicator that content is loading. There're only so many ways of displaying hierarchical data.

Comment: @dzed so is your question more about how to have meaningful transitions between layers when instant shifts aren't possible?

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes partially it is, problem is when to start loading (click/double click) and how to display it. My main problem though is that alternative 1 in image above is easier to use you select a region and then you can load and work with the data. In alternative 2 i have a tree-view with all regions and its data where user can easily jump between data and have a more complete overview though the hierarchy will be way more deeper than in alternative 1. How do I make this complex data structure easy to use?

Comment: Could you edit that information more explicitly into your question? I think right now people might think it's a duplicate of the other question, which isn't quite the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea here comes from Windows Explorer where you can have a pretty deep hierarchy.

Assumptions I am making about your issue

1. You have to see all of the regions at once
2. You should be able to see multiple nodes at once

One solution is to allow users to make favourites or shortcuts to their favourite nodes. So this would be going with alternative 2 with lazy loading and if you right click on it you can say "Make Favourite" or "Create shortcut"

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB6y0i.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This way users can go back to the node they want to in the future easily in one click once they have found it. This is analogous to a bookmark

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Especially "muliple nodes" reasoning.

Comment: Thank, you for your reply i have done some user test and alternative 1 in my post was the way to go where we separated the region three and the data tree. I like the favourite functionallity that i am considering in adding to the region tree. I am marking your post as answer because of the "Make Favourite" suggestion.

Comment: I like your favorites idea. Tree-hierarchy is just straight hell. I'm working on a project where a customer had got 33.000 nodes/folders in a tree. How can you do wayfinding?! It's a disaster. With bookmarking/favorites you can have shortcuts to the cumbersome task of finding the right entity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to lazy load the children. To display the tree all you need is header data for the nodes in the tree such as:

- name
- icon
- color

The rest of the data for a tree node  could be lazy loaded when the user actually tries to do something with the node.

Which approach you should use I think depends on the *number of nodes* at each level. If there are a lot of nodes in the leafs then at Explorer approach would be useful: 2 columns,  one for parent nodes  and one for leaf nodes. Otherwise  the user will end up scrolling a lot up and down.

If you have space available for it, the **column mode** of the Mac OS X Finder is probably the best approach. It is easy to navigate and gives a good overview.  You avoid the awkward scrolling up and down that you get a lot of in trees with a lot of data.

But I think you should also ask yourself whether the data naturally fits into a hierarchy. Perhaps *sets* would be more useful. By that I mean using **tags** as commonly done on photo management applications such as iPhoto or Aperture and in some e-mail applications such as Gmail. Using the tag approach allows you to to have a more shallow hierarchy.

Comment: You have some good point here, and tags are unfortunately not possible to use at the moment because we need to display the region tree and show the relationship between the "region" nodes.